# Как установить APSW модуль для Python на Windows?

Tags: python

> apsw-3.12.2.post1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
>
> [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#apsw](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#apsw)

при команде : pip install apsw-3.12.2.post1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl

#### Ошибка:

```
C:\Users\UserName>pip install apsw-3.12.2.post1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
Requirement 'apsw-3.12.2.post1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
Processing c:\users\UserName\apsw-3.12.2.post1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\UserName\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\UserName\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 310, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "c:\users\UserName\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 748, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "c:\users\UserName\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 360, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "c:\users\UserName\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 577, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "c:\users\UserName\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 798, in unpack_url
    unpack_file_url(link, location, download_dir, hashes=hashes)
  File "c:\users\UserName\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 705, in unpack_file_url
    unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
  File "c:\users\UserName\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 599, in unpack_file
    flatten=not filename.endswith('.whl')
  File "c:\users\UserName\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 482, in unzip_file
    zipfp = open(filename, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\UserName\\apsw-3.12.2.post1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl'
```

Comment: На той же страничке ведь [написано](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/): *Use pip version 8 or newer to install the downloaded .whl files.*

Comment: Что происходит если выполнить `pip install *.whl`?

Comment: ошибка говорит, что файла не существует в директории `c:\users\UserName`. Если вы загрузили `apsw*.whl` в какое-то другое место, то укажите полный путь к этому файлу. Кстати, если у вас 64-битная Windows, то вам нужен файл с amd64 в имени.

Comment: @jfs, почему для 64-битной нужен amd64? Это ведь необязательно: на 64-х ведь и 32-х тоже работают. Да и версию питона, для amd64 тоже, наверное, нужно 64-битную...

Comment: Конечно, если питон 32-битный, то и модуль расширения 32-битный ставьте.